# Amazon EC2: How install glassfish in EC2?

Tags: glassfish, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud, glassfish-3

i'm trying to deploy my JSF site in EC2 instances, i'm new with cloud computing.

How do i install the GassFish 3 OpenSource in my EC2 instance ?

Update:
To download use 'curl' command :

```
curl http://www.java.net/download/jdk6/6u27/promoted/b03/binaries/jdk-6u27-ea-bin-b03-linux-i586-27_may_2011-rpm.bin > java-rpm.bin
```

or using wget:

```
wget http://www.java.net/download/jdk6/6u27/promoted/b03/binaries/jdk-6u27-ea-bin-b03-linux-i586-27_may_2011-rpm.bin
```

Comment: EC2 once launched it's same as regular machine. You can sownload Glassfish using `wget` or something. Perform regular install. Deploy your app. Done. Ideally, you'd like to bundle your instance with Glassfish as an AMI for future uses.

Comment: @Nishant, yes this is what i want to do, to bundle my instance to my AMI, if not they gonna charge me even when the site is not been used right ?
Is possible to bundle it ?

Comment: Define what you mean by "not being used". They don't charge you if you terminate machine, but whenever it runs you will be charged, regardless there is any traffic or not. But you need to have at least one instance running to handle requests.

Comment: @okrasz, i mean it is when to website is not running then my instance is stopped, i would be charge only when someone is seeing my website, this is what i mean it.
is this possible though ?

Comment: When your instance is stopped noone can access your website. If they enter your URL they will have connection timeout. Amazon won't instantiate you instance for an incoming requests. PaaS works this way not IaaS. For PaaS check Heroku, Google Apps Engine, CloudBees (probably). Amazon has Elastic Beanstalk as a PaaS offer, but there I think at least one instance is always running.

Comment: Attention, if you terminate your instance it's not completely true you're not charged: for instance Elastic IP Addresses on Amazon EC2 are free unless you don’t use them. This is a strange business model but it prevents people assigning themselves IP addresses which they don’t use. So be aware!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you  need to do:

1. Get an [AMI instance launched](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?creating-an-ami-ebs.html). Follow [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGkd3-s9Z5U) to install. (Unfortunately, Glassfish installation tutorials are given as YouTube video on their official website!) 
    The Simplest is to start with an existing EBS backed instance. This is how I started.
2. Now, if you want to kill the instance, it's same as throwing machine out of window. If you want to reuse it later or probably want to make a blue print for many instances that you will be launching in future. You need to bundle it up and register as an image.

   If you have EBS backed instance, creating an image out of it is easier than sending an email. All you need to do is to login to your AWS Web Console, select the instance that you wanted to create an AMI of, select `Instance Actions > Create Image` from menu. Done!

   If you have instance storage based AMI. You need to bundle up, and store in your S3 bucket, and register the AMI using, [ec2-api-tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) and [ec2-ami-tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/368). So, have them installed in your instance and create the image as very neatly [explained here](http://support.rightscale.com/12-Guides/Dashboard_Users_Guide/Clouds/AWS_Global/Image_Locator/Actions/Register_an_AMI).

Now, as far as cost is concerned, [refer this](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/). As far as I understand (my clients pay, so I don't really know how much) your running instance is going to cost you some money, even if there is no activity. However, if you make an AMI and store in S3 or in a EBS volume, you will be paying for storage cost.

Hope this explains what you wanted.

Comment: thanks by your explanation, i already have S3 service, it think this gonna work =)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install jdk and then set environment variable JAVA_HOME.
Then follow below commands (Applicable on Amazon Linux EC2 ):

Directory used here is : usr/server

wget http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/4.1.2/release/glassfish-4.1.2.zip

unzip glassfish-4.1.2.zip

mv glassfish4 ../server/

groupadd glassfish-group

useradd -s /bin/bash -g glassfish-group glassfish-user

cd usr/server

chown -Rf glassfish-user.glassfish-group glassfish4

ls -l | grep glassfish

cd glassfish4

cd glassfish/domains

cd glassfish/bin

pwd

cd /etc/init.d/

wget https://geekstarts.info/scripts/glassfish.sh

mv glassfish.sh glassfish

chmod 755 glassfish

ls -l | grep glassfish

cd ~ glassfish/

su vector-user

whoami

pwd

cd glassfish4/bin

ls -l

whoami

./asadmin

change-master-password --savemasterpassword   // default is chageit

change-admin-password    // default is blank

start-domain

enable-secure-admin

restart-domain

stop-domain